# VBA WORD: find a paragraph that has a specific style

Tags: vba, ms-word, styles, paragraph

I am trying to write a code in VBA, where I will get the number of a paragraph that will have a specific  style (let's say Heading 1).
I am going through a loop and unfortunately I am getting such an error:

```
"Object variable or With block variable not set"
```

Here is my code:

```
Public Function FindParagraph(ByVal pStyle As String) As Integer
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim pNum As Integer
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    For pNum = 1 To doc.Paragraphs.Count
        Debug.Print pNum, doc.Paragraphs(pNum).Range.Style
        If doc.Paragraphs(pNum).Range.Style = pStyle Then
            FindParagraph = pNum
            Exit For
        End If
    Next pNum
End Function

Sub DoSth()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = FindParagraph("Heading 1")
    Debug.Print i
End Sub
```

Debugger shows that the problem is in this line:
`pStyle = doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Style`
And actually I am looking at my Word document and it is the first line of the Table of Contents.
Do You know why is it like this?

Comment: Just a helpful hint regarding editing your question.  If you have had responses and other answers then you should not change the original question but should add to it (See my answer) so that any comments and responses you had in relation to the original question still make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided does not compile.  It gives an error at

```
While Not (IsEmpty(pStyle))
```

because  the Method IsEmpty should only be used on a Variant type and the type you have assigned to pStyle is a String.   To achieve your intent you will need to change this line to

```
While Not pStyle = vbNullString
```

Updated to provide revised function

```
Sub TestFindParagraph()

    Dim IsFound As Boolean
    IsFound = FindParagraph(ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory), "Heading 1")

End Sub


Public Function FindParagraph(ByVal SearchRange As Word.Range, ByVal ParaStyle As String) As Long

    Dim ParaIndex As Long
    For ParaIndex = 1 To SearchRange.Paragraphs.Count

        If doc.Paragraphs(ParaIndex).Range.Style = ParaStyle Then

            FindParagraph = ParaIndex
            Exit Function

        End If

    Next

End Function
```

**Update 2020-Apr-15  Resolving the TOC issue**

The code posted by the OP and by myself both fail when the paragraph is a Table of Contents field.  This failure occurs because of the default member feature of VBA Objects.

The default member of an object is a method that is called if the object instance is given without a qualifying Method. This feature can be helpful as it simplifies code, but, can lead to strange errors similar to that which we are experiencing.

In Word, Styles are objects with numerous properties and methods.  The default Method of Style is NameLocal (See the object browser for Word.Style) which returns a Variant containing a string (See the type for style in the locals windows). 
 Consequently, even though pStyle is defined as a String type, VBA coercion allows the variant/string to be assigned to the String pStyle and everything appears to be OK.

However, in the case of a TOC field it appears that Word does not return the style  wrapping the TOC field, instead it returns the value of 'nothing' i.e. there is no style for a TOC.  Nothing (not the same as vbNullString) cannot be assigned to a string and consequently an error occurs.

There would appear to be two solutions to the problem encountered above.

1. Change the code to use correct syntax for the information we require.  i.e. Style.NameLocal. Unfortunately, this solution will also fail because we cannot call a method (NameLocal) on an object that is nothing.
2. Change the type of variable for pStyle from String to Variant.  Variant types can hold objects and consequently can hold the value of nothing which is generated when a paragraph is a TOC field.

Solution 2 would appear to work fine however from a purist perspective you would have an intermediate variant variable that captures the result from Style and then tests the variant for nothing before assigning the string value or vbNullString to pStyle.

Final Update 2020-Apr-15

I was unfortunatly called away by Mrs F for some urgent jobs so forgot to add this final peice.

The Default member trap can be avoided easily.  This is due to the amazing work done by the folks over at Rubberduck.

http://rubberduckvba.com/

The Rubberduck addin for VBA (which is free) has, as one of its many talents, a much more rigorous code analysis (Code Inspections) of VBA. One of the inspections is to warn wherever a default member has been used in code.  Rubberduck really does remove a significant amount of pain when writing VBA code as it helps you understand just exactly the assumptions you have made in your code (that you didn't realise you'd made)...

Comment: Not really.  "While Not pStyle <> "Heading 1" is a double negative so you are really saying "While  pStyle = "Heading 1" so the loop won't do anything if the first paragraph is not "Heading 1".  I suspect you mean  "While pStyle <> "Heading 1".  You also have an error in the location of  i = i + 1.  It should come after the "pStyle=...." line.  Why?, because you set i as 1 before you start the loop and then the first action in the loop is to set i=i+1, so you start testing pstyle with a value of i=2.  Your code will also produce an error if you never find a "Heading 1"

Comment: I updated my answer with an revised function for you

Comment: This post may also be interesting http://vba.relief.jp/word-vba-get-index-number-of-current-paragraph/

Comment: I understand the code but I still do not know why am I getting this error when TOC is reached by the debugger. Do You have any idea why?

Comment: Are there any paragraphs after the TOC?

Comment: You should also consider the i=i+1.  If you have 10 paragraphs in your document, your code will fail if it doesn't find "Heading 1" in the first 10 paragraphs  because your code continues to paragraph 11 and beyond and you can't test what doesn't exist.  Do you get the same problem with my code?

Comment: YES, there are many paragraphs. There is a paragraph Table of contents. It is OK.
Then there is the first empty from the TOC and it is NOT OK. 
What is interesting the second TOC entry is OK. 
This is what I do not understand.

Comment: I am getting an error:
`Run-time error '424': Object required`
for this line
`If doc.Paragraphs(ParaIndex).Range.Style = ParaStyle Then`

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with a document containing a TOC.  I will investigate further.

Comment: What is curious is the fact that if I delete TOC from my document the code works and it find the paragraph :).I will add my new code to my first message/

Comment: «I still do not know why am I getting this error when TOC is reached» Probably because you attached the TOC to a paragraph to which the Heading 1 Style is applied.

Comment: @macropod, It seems that You're right. Thanks for this advice.

Comment: I've found the reason there is a problem and updated my answer above to explain the problem and the solution to it.

Comment: @freeflow Thank You very much for such an extensive and helpful response!

Comment: Unfortunately using `Variant` type does not give a positive effect.

My problem is the following. I have a group of tables that I want to change the style of. However, tables are in different parts of document. 
So I want to set the range of the document and do actions for the tables only in a specific range. 
This is why I needed to find a special paragraph number as I do not have any other idea how to set such a range.

Comment: I feel your pain.  However this is now a new topic so you should open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for a paragraph in Word to not have a paragraph Style, so testing for whether a paragraph lacks any Style at all is pointless.

Also, looping through all paragraphs is much less efficient than using Find. For example, the following code retrieves the paragraph index # of each Heading 1:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  Set Rng = .Duplicate
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Style = wdStyleHeading1
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = i + 1
    Rng.End = .Duplicate.End
    MsgBox Rng.Paragraphs.Count
    'The next If ... End If block is only needed if the Found content might be in a table
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      If .End = .Cells(1).Range.End - 1 Then
        .End = .Cells(1).Range.End
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        If .Information(wdAtEndOfRowMarker) = True Then
          .End = .End + 1
        End If
      End If
    End If
    'The next line is only needed if the Found content might include the document's final paragraph break
    If .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End Then Exit Do
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " instances found."
End Sub
```

More code, but much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `for i=1 to ....Count`
try `for each` loop for better efficency

```
Private Sub StylesCount()
    Dim p As Paragraph
    Dim story As Range
    Dim counter As Long

    For Each story In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        For Each p In story.Paragraphs
            If StrComp(p.Style, "Heading 1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next p
    Next story

    Debug.Print counter

End Sub
```

Its works for paragraph styles. For character styles you should use .find method.